# Crossvalidation in Stanford NER

Tags: stanford-nlp, cross-validation

I'm trying to use cross validation in [Stanford NER](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml). The [feature factory](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/NERFeatureFactory.html) lists 3 properties:

```
numFolds    int 1   The number of folds to use for cross-validation.
startFold   int 1   The starting fold to run.
numFoldsToRun   int 1   The number of folds to run.
```

which I think should be used for cross validation. But I don't think they actually work. Setting numFolds to 1 or 10 doesn't change the running time for training at all. And strangely, using numFoldsToRun gives the following warning:

```
Unknown property: |numFoldsToRun|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. These options haven't been implemented. If you want to run cross-validation experiments, you'll have to do it completely manually by preparing the data sets yourself. (Sorry!)