# Evaluate Stanford NER CRF and compute Precision/Recall programmatically

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Does Stanford NER have a class/method to calculate Precision/Recall in Java (not command line)?

I have been able to train my model on my training data like this in Java:

```
Properties props = StringUtils.propFileToProperties("classifierTraining/austen.prop");
SeqClassifierFlags flags = new SeqClassifierFlags(props);
CRFClassifier<CoreLabel> crf = new CRFClassifier<CoreLabel>(flags);
crf.train();
crf.serializeClassifier("classifierTraining/model.ser.gz");
```

1. Is it possible to perform cross-validation on a test dataset programmatically with the Stanford NLP package? I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882294/crossvalidation-in-stanford-ner) from three years ago, which said "no" at the time.
2. Is there a way to run the trained classifier on a test dataset programmatically in Java, and get precision/recall values (without using command line)? This way, I should be able to manually split the dataset and run the code on it for cross-validaiton.

UPDATE: I realized in the new 3.7.0 package, I can use the following to get precision, recall and F1, but that's average for all kinds of entities (Persons, organizations, locations). Is there a way to get them for particular entities?

```
Triple<Double,Double,Double> scores = crf.classifyAndWriteAnswers("classifierTraining/testFileTokenized.txt", true);
```

Comment: Did you ever find a way to achieve this?

Comment: No. The closest is the last line of code I've included above.

Comment: I also think this would be a particularly useful feature to have. The code is there, using the CLI I can see the entity specific metrics. Maybe you could suggest it at https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues

Comment: If the CLI version does print per entity results then one must be able to find the code somewhere. Strangely I looked into `CRFClassifier.java` and `AbstractSequenceClassifier.java` and seem to only be able to find code that outputs one single set of (Precision, Recall, F1) scores instead of multiple sets of per entity scores.

Answer (score 1):

Scanning through the CRFClassifier class shows that the following function is used for logging

```
Triple<Double,Double,Double> classifyAndWriteAnswers(Collection<List<IN>> documents,
                                                              PrintWriter printWriter,
                                                              DocumentReaderAndWriter<IN> readerWriter,
                                                              boolean outputScores)
```

The above function `classifyAndWriteAnswers` calls `Triple<Double,Double,Double> printResults(Counter<String> entityTP, Counter<String> entityFP, Counter<String> entityFN)` which prints out all the metrics using Redwood logger.

A simple hack is to just import Redwood logger in your class which has `main()` and configure it so that all the metrics are displayed.

Import: `import edu.stanford.nlp.util.logging.*;`

and add this inside your main()
`StanfordRedwoodConfiguration.setup();`

then just call any implementation of `classifyAndWriteAnswers` with `outputScores = true`